# Method loops - java- Error within "Do you want to continue" Method

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to write a program using methods. This is my given problem

"At the 10$ store nothing is more than $10.00.  Prompt the user for the price of their item (.50 cents to $9.99 dollars) using the getRangedDouble method and continue to input items as long as they indicate that they have more using your getYNConfirm method.  Display the total cost of the item(s) to 2 decimal places with printf.

I have gotten the getRangedDouble to work and display correct values within the range, however I am struggling with getting the Y/NConfirm method. It is described as "This is an input method that gets a Yes or No [Y/N] returning true for yes and false for no.  It should accept yYnN as valid responses and loop until it gets one of them."

This is the code that I have for YNConfirm

```
public static String getYNConfirm(Scanner pipe, String prompt)
{
   boolean done = false;
   boolean response = false;
  String YNResp = "";
  String trash = "";
   do
   {
       System.out.println(prompt);
    YNResp = pipe.nextLine();
    if(YNResp.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
    {
        done = true;
        response = false;
        
    }
    if(YNResp.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
    {
        done = true;
        response = true;
    }
    else
    {
        trash = pipe.nextLine();    
        System.out.println("Please input Y/N. You input: " + trash); 
    }
   }while(!done);
return YNResp;}
```

My goal is by having the YNConfirm give response = true/false I can take that variable and plug it into my main program. if it is true it will loop back and ask for more items to be entered, and if it is false it will display the total cost, here is what my main code looks like.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  double item = 0;
  String YNResp = "";
  double price = 0;
  boolean response = false;
  do{
      item = SafeInput.getRangedDouble(in, "Please insert the item price", .50, 9.99);
     double totalPrice = price + item;
      in.NextLine();

    YNResp = SafeInput.getYNConfirm(in, "Do you have more items?");
    if(response==false) 
    {
      System.out.printf("Your total price is" + totalPrice);
    }
    else
    {
        response = true;
        System.out.printf("Your total price is" + totalPrice);
      }
  }while(!response);
    
}
```

if Y/N confirms that it is false then it should continue to ask for more items until the value is true, then if it is true it should just output the total price. The file runs, but it doesn't loop back to asking the user to input their next item, I get something like this.

```
Please insert the item price[0.5 - 9.99]: 1.2
Do you have more items?
y
y
Please input Y/N. You input: y
Your total price is1.0
Please insert the item price[0.5 - 9.99]:
```

Comment: Look at the error message you get when you compile. What is that telling you? Also look at the bodies of the two `if` statements in `getYNConfirm`. Are they different? Should they be?

Comment: What does the single `=` in `if(response=false){` do?

Comment: Finally, once you get your code to compile, step through it with the debugger.

Comment: Put an additional `else ` before `if(YNResp.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))` and remove `trash = pipe.nextLine();`

Comment: Reason: You check the input for being Y/y. Next, you check the input for being N/n or something else, which includes the previously checked Yes answer. In the `else` part wait for another input `trash`)  but do nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is by having the YNConfirm give response = true/false

```java
private static boolean isYesAnswer() {
  return "y".equalsIgnoreCase(
    new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()
  );
}
```